# Tips for running the program Cannot find any provider supporting RSA

Tags: java

The server and the local code are consistent, there is no problem running locally, and the prompt for remote operation,jdk version is 1.8.0.161. error message

```html
    java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:540)
        at com.shineyue.sdk.encrypt.RSACoder.decryptByPublicKey(RSACoder.java:52
)
        at com.shineyue.sdk.core.DataPlatFormService.uploadTwo(DataPlatFormServi
ce.java:317)
        at com.shineyue.sdk.core.DataPlatFormApi.upload(DataPlatFormApi.java:96)

        at com.jason.invokerWs.provider.task.TokenManager.uploadData(TokenManage
r.java:273)
        at com.jason.invokerWs.provider.task.TokenManager.run(TokenManager.java:
162)
        at com.jason.invokerWs.provider.task.InvokerAPI.execute(InvokerAPI.java:
50)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.j
ava:573)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem will not appear in Eclipse direct startup, but it will appear when deployed to the server.
Cause: An error occurred during the decryption step, and no provider related to decryption-related algorithms such as RSA / ECB / PKCS1Padding was found.
Solution: Add sunjce_provider.jar in the $ {JAVA_HOME} \ lib \ ext directory to the classpath directory.